# Soundflower audio from the iOS simulator is in mono, not stereo

Tags: macos, audio, mono

I'm using Soundflower on OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4 to route my audio-out to audio-in. This works great for iTunes or Spotify, but when I record audio from the iOS simulator the audio only comes out from my right headphone (I'm not really sure if that means its mono, or if it's dropping a channel).

I've tested playing audio through SoundflowerBed to my headphones, and also capturing the audio and streaming it to an iPod to be played back. In both cases, the audio only comes out the right earphone. SoundflowerBed is using the maximum buffer size of 2048.

Does anyone know what would cause only the iOS simulator to play mono audio through Soundflower, or have a potential fix?

I'm also looking into other solutions besides Soundflower, but it looks like Jack only works for applications that support it (i.e. not the iOS simulator), and Audio Hijack Pro may only support recording to files rather than rerouting (haven't looked into that program much). If it were possible to route the headphone jack into the microphone jack with some sort of cable, that would work too.

Edit: I think this question could use the tag 'Soundflower' but I don't have enough rep on SU to craete new tags.

Edit2: I found a fork of Soundflower called [WavTap](https://github.com/pje/WavTap). It does the same thing as Soundflower but it also records to a WAV file. Interestingly, when I play back the WAV file it has both channels of audio, though it still only plays through the right headphone when streaming to the iPod touch. I'm going to look into what WavTap is doing when recording to the WAV file -- something they're doing is fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I haven't worked out a solution with Soundflower, or an alternative called Jack (when the simulator audio is routed to Jack it crashes the iOS app running inside of it).

Unfortunately, my conclusion at this point is that a 3.5mm male-to-male cable (just a regular auxiliary cord) is the best approach. It's reliable, won't cause crashes, and provides stereo sound.

The cord has the downsides of cost and having to buy and plugin hardware (which is harder in a mac colo setup). Additionally, you won't be able to selectively route audio from certain applications and not others – but this disadvantage is true for Soundflower as well.